# split row and make new columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Apologies if this question has been asked earlier. I have a pandas dataframe which contains 2447660 rows. I want split the rows by 1564 and create new 1564 columns. For example, lets say I have 10 rows in a dataframe as below,

```
         Col
0         1.860
1        -2.834
2        -2.518
3        -3.591
4         0.919
5         0.985
6        -2.465
7         0.942
8         0.945
9        -2.589
```

and I want to split it by 2 and create 5 new columns (column names are not important)

```
         Col     col1    col2    col3      col5
0        1.860   -2.518   0.919  -2.465    0.945
1        -2.834  -3.591   0.985   0.942   -2.589
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use numpy to reshape the body of the dataframe (here, -1 means "calculate the appropriate number based on the data size"):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.Col.to_numpy().reshape((-1, 5)))
```

Then generate new column names:

```
df1.columns = [f'col{i+1}' for i in range(df1.shape[1])]

print(df1)
#    col1   col2   col3   col4   col5
#0  1.860 -2.834 -2.518 -3.591  0.919
#1  0.985 -2.465  0.942  0.945 -2.589
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
def split_frame(df, cols):
    rslt = []
    rsd = None
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        if i%cols == 0:
            if rsd is not None:
                rslt.append(rsd)
            else:
                rsd = [None]*cols
        c = i%cols        
        rsd[c] = df.iloc[i][0]
    rslt.append(rsd)
    return pd.DataFrame(data=rslt)
```

Given your sample dataframe

```
split_df =split_frame(sample_dataframe , 5)
```

Yields:

```
    0         1       2       3       4
0   0.985   -2.465  0.942   0.945   -2.589
1   0.985   -2.465  0.942   0.945   -2.589
```